# ios distribution provisioning profile deleted

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

My app is online now, and users can download it from app store. I accidentally deleted the distribution provisioning profile it uses from my developer center and would this affect users to download my app from app store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this will not make any effect on your live apps.